# Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Offline Files do not work

Tags: windows-7, offline-files

I have Windows 7 Pro 64-bit on my laptop and I use it to access folders shared from the desktop. The desktop has Windows XP Pro and Arch Linux (both 32-bit) installed in dual-boot. Sometimes I boot my desktop in Windows, and sometimes in Linux, so I have set up both OSes to share the same folders with the same names (from Linux via Samba). Client-side caching is allowed on the desktop.
I made some subfolders of the shares available offline on the laptop. This worked for a while, but then problems started to emerge. The symptoms are:

1. I cannot make any file/folder available offline, nor can I sync those that seem to be available. When I try to do this from a context menu nothing happens, but when I try it via Properties window, it says something like "Windows cannot access ." (not sure: I have Russian Windows) and the error code is 0x80004005 "Unknown Error."
2. Some folders say they are available offline at the bottom of Explorer window when selected, but none of them really is available offline and none of them has that green circle with arrows at its icon. These folders appear available even after client side cache has been cleared and relocated several times, and offline files fuctionality has been turned off and back on.
3. (Not sure if it is abnormal) Under the network name of my desktop in Explorer (viewed from the laptop) I see two folders with the same name, and after hovering mouse over one of them I get a hint that reads "[Offline Share]". This twin folder disappears when I disable offline files. I made hidden and protected system files invisible in Folder Options and the twin was still there, so, apparently, my system doesn't consider it hidden or system folder. I do not recall having this twin around when offline files were working well.

So, the question is what is wrong with my offline files and can I get them back without reinstalling Windows on my laptop?